# iframe elements not aligning as expected

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS - trying to align 3 iframe elements horizontally (YouTube embeds) like this:

`left            center         right`

and here's how it looks right now:

`left
                 center
                                right`

I tried using `display: inline-block;` but it doesn't seem to help.
Using `display: block;` aligns it nicely, although vertically - I need it done horizontally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<style>

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hepta+Slab&display=swap');

body {
    background-image: url("ice_cube_bg.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
}

.cube {
    font-family: 'Hepta Slab', serif;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

iframe {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

</style>

<html>
<main>
<body>

<title>ICE CUBE</title>
<div>
    <div class="cube_text">
    <center class="cube">cube</center>
    </div>
    <div align="left">
    <iframe width="500" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4gyt9yqDMdA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div align="center">
    <iframe width="500" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/w1KkptqwfLE" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div align="right">
    <iframe width="500" height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/izofEX-NQEU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</main>
</html>
```

How it looks:

[image: How it looks]

How it should look:

[image: How it should look]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div` elements are `display: block` by default, so they trigger new lines.

Remove the div elements. You appear to be only using them for the `align` attribute which was superceeded by CSS in 1996.

To align the iframe elements, put them in a `display: flex` container with `justify-content: space-between`.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between
}
```

```html
<div>
  <iframe width="150" height="100" src="//example.com/"></iframe>
  <iframe width="150" height="100" src="//example.com/"></iframe>
  <iframe width="150" height="100" src="//example.com/"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of display block, you can use display flex.

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>ICE CUBE</title>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hepta+Slab&display=swap');

        body {
            background-image: url("ice_cube_bg.jpg");
            background-size: 100%;
        }

        .cube {
            font-family: 'Hepta Slab', serif;
            font-size: 50px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        iframe {
            display: inline-block;
            border-radius: 10px;
        }

        .alignItems {
            display: flex;
        }

        .addPadding {
            padding: 1em;
            width: 33%;
        }

        iframe {
            width: 100%
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <div class="cube_text">
            <center class="cube">cube</center>
        </div>
        <div class="alignItems">
            <div class="addPadding" align="left">
                <iframe height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4gyt9yqDMdA" frameborder="0"
                    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                    allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="addPadding" align="center">
                <iframe height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/w1KkptqwfLE" frameborder="0"
                    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                    allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="addPadding" align="right">
                <iframe height="350" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/izofEX-NQEU" frameborder="0"
                    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                    allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```